# How to load MALLET LDA model state from R?

Tags: r, mallet

I have been using the `mallet` package in R that wraps MALLET. So far so good, but I was wondering how I can save and load th model state on the disk, so that I don't have to train all over and get a different model each time.

For the saving part it seems that `model$writeState()` does the trick, although this function is a bit undocumented. The complete code for saving the model state would be something like

```
model <- trainLDA(mallet.instances, 30)
model$writeState('model.state.gz')
```

Loading still remains a mystery to me. Perhaps calling a method from the base class `ParallelTopicModel` but don't really now how to do it in `rJava`

Comment: any update about this?